# How to set autonumeric jquery for a currency value in PHP Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I am using [autonumeric jquery](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric) to using separator on the money value. My problem is when I want to see the detail page, I want to set the estimated value field and I can edit too in this page. If I am not using autonumeric jquery, I can set it with this code below:

```
<input class="form-control edit" name="v_led_estimatevalue" value="{{ $leads[0]->LED_ESTIMATEVALUE }}" placeholder="" vMin='0'  disabled>
```

But how to set it with autonumeric jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Thanks to Alex who answered my question. I really appreciate that. But the answer is still give me an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: AutoNumeric is not defined`.
I already find out the right one, I give an id in my input and put this code on js:

```
$('#v_led_estimatevalue').autoNumeric("init", {
  aSep: '.',
  aDec: ',',
  vMin: '0',
  unSetOnSubmit: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to set autoNumeric field value in exactly same way as for a simple input field, like this: `<input type="text" value="1234.56">`

[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwwdg8ot/2/),
[autoNumeric documentation](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric#on-input-elements)